# analyzer_plugin generates Legacy protocol of Dart analyzer server instead of LSP

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol, dart-analyzer

I try to write some custom lint rules. To achieve this, I used the [analyzer_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer_plugin) package and I set up my project as it should be. Here is a simplified excerpt of the main class :

```dart
class LintAnalyzerPlugin extends ServerPlugin {

  @override
  Future<void> analyzeFile({required AnalysisContext analysisContext, required String path}) async {

    channel.sendNotification(
      AnalysisErrorsParams(path, [getAnalysisError(path)]).toNotification(),
    );
  }
}
```

channel.sendNotification is called but no message is displayed into VS Code Problems panel.

After some investigation, I found out that the JSON generated for the sent notification use Dart server Legacy protocol. But the Dart analyzer server run by [Dart Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code) wait for LSP (Microsoft Language Server Protocol).

Fortunately the extension offers a setting to start the server with the Legacy protocol:

```
"dart.useLegacyAnalyzerProtocol": true
```

And now the VS Code Problems panel populates sent notifications.

Unfortunately Dart Code extension [advises to use LSP because the Legacy protocol will eventually be removed some day](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartuselegacyanalyzerprotocol).

Is it possible to generate LSP? Or did I miss something?

If anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears.

Comment: Have you tried reviewing the issues on the package, or filing one yourself?  That's probably better than asking on SO.

Comment: You can also ask on the discord server for DartCode.  There's a link to it on the project source.

Comment: @alexis-bg, have you found a solution to this issue ? I currently try to achieve a working demo of analyzer_plugin : https://github.com/evaisse/dart_demo_analyzer_plugin

I struggle with this error using android studio in the analyzer status webpage: "Unrecorded error while starting the plugin."